# How can I save JWT token in AppStream 2.0 in a safe way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appstream

I have a legacy desktop application that is usually deployed on the user's machine. It takes a username and a password and communicates with the cloud to get a JWT token which is stored in the registry. For the subsequent run, we check the JWT token and get the entitlement.

Since, AppStream 2.0 fleet is ephemeral, I am not sure if I save this way, the data will persist. Is there any safe way to persist this user-specific token in AppStream 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to persist the token in the registry.
There is an AWS blog post that outlines the procedure of persisting the user-specific registry (i.e. "The tree of registry entries rooted at HKEY_CURRENT_USER"). [1]

You must enable *Application Settings Persistence* for this to work.

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-appstream-2-0-new-application-settings-persistence-and-a-quick-launch-recap/ ("Application Settings Persistence")